# How to make a character in a list appear only once?

Tags: python, list, fractions

```
ilist1 = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

In the above list, "1" would appear twice. I need the program to only let it appear once in the new list.

Comment: Your question is now very much a duplicate; your previous revision at least made your post *somewhat* unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a set comprehension instead:

```
fracs = {str(Fraction(x, y)) for x in ilist1 for y in ilist2}
```

A set can only hold unique values, so any `1/3` duplicates are removed.

Note that you are not producing 4 combinations of pairs formed of elements in `ilist1` and `ilist2`. You are producing the *product* of the two lists, so 4 * 4 = 16 combinations. If you expected to only get 4, you'll need to use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
fracs = {str(Fraction(x, y)) for x, y in zip(ilist1, ilist2)}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> ilist1 = [-1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> ilist2 = [-3, 3, 6, 9]
>>> {str(Fraction(x, y)) for x in ilist1 for y in ilist2}
set(['1/6', '1/3', '1/2', '-2/3', '1/9', '-1/3', '2/9', '1', '-1', '-1/6', '-1/9', '2/3'])
>>> {str(Fraction(x, y)) for x, y in zip(ilist1, ilist2)}
set(['1/3'])
```

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks. I'll choose your accept your answer ASAP.

Comment: Oh another thing. Is there a way to remove the "set()" in the result?

Comment: @VaguelyUnderstandable: you can always turn it back into a list with `list(fracs)`.